# how to convert list to number and add them up (python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can one convert a list of `list` into `int`, and then add them up?

The current result is `[[1],[2],[3],[4]]`. I would like to remove those `[]` and them add them up into a single `int`.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to iterate through your list of lists yet? (Iterating on lists typically looks like `for elem in somelist:...` If you did, what happened? If not, give it a shot and post back your results. I'm sure we can help guide you through something that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `list of list of int`
You can do this by using a `for loop`

```
>>> vList = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
>>> vsum = 0
>>> for x in vList:
...     for y in x:
...         vsum += y
... 
>>> vsum
10
```

Or you can do this by [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> sum([y for x in vList for y in x])
10
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it! The problem was solved with your simple direct answer!

Answer (score 1):

How about that

```
l = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]

def value(l):
    return sum([i[0] for i in l])

print value(l)
```

OR

```
sum(sum(l, []))    #works on lists of lists only.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
def Flatten(*args):
    for x in args:
        if hasattr(x, '__iter__'):
            for y in Flatten(*x):
                yield y
        else:
            yield x

output = sum(Flatten(input))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would normally call this a duplicate because what you are looking for is how to [flatten a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python).

But the answer is using [list comprehension](http://List%20comprehensions) which makes a little too difficult to read.

Here is their answer:

```
>>> list = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
>>> [item for sublist in list for item in sublist]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here it is simplified

```
anotherList = []

for item in list:
    for anotherItem in item:
        anotherList.append(anotherItem)

print anotherList
```

Now adding:

```
def sumList(aList):
    result = 0
    for i in aList:
        result+=i
    return result

print sumList(anotherList)
```